# Additional information: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'BtLib.dll' ni una de sus dependencias

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, pervasive

I have the following code.

```
 public CuentasCobrarBL(string rutaDatos)
        {
            rutaDirec = new CompanyBL(rutaDatos).rutaDirectorio;
            CompanyBL companybl = new CompanyBL(rutaDatos);
            Compania compania =  companybl.CargarCompania();
}




public ilimitada.Dominio.Pervasive.SCI.Core.Entidades.Compania CargarCompania()
        {
            ilimitada.Dominio.Pervasive.SCI.Core.Entidades.Compania companium = null;
            using (IPervasive<ilimitada.Dominio.Pervasive.SCI.Core.DAO.Estructuras.Compania> pervasive = BtrieveDataProvider<ilimitada.Dominio.Pervasive.SCI.Core.DAO.Estructuras.Compania>.Create(this.rutaDirectorio, 999))
            {
                //    pervasive.DataBuffer = new ilimitada.Dominio.Pervasive.SCI.Core.DAO.Estructuras.Compania();
                //    int num = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf<ilimitada.Dominio.Pervasive.SCI.Core.DAO.Estructuras.Compania>(new ilimitada.Dominio.Pervasive.SCI.Core.DAO.Estructuras.Compania());
                //    if (pervasive.Open(OpenMode.Normal))
                //    {
                //        if (pervasive.GetFirst())
                //        {
                //            companium = CompaniaCV.ConvertirEstructuraEnObjeto(pervasive.DataBuffer);
                //        }
                //    }
            }
            return companium;
        }
```

The using line is throwing me this exception.

> Additional information: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
>   'BtLib.dll' ni una de sus dependencias. No se puede encontrar el
>   módulo especificado.

The BRetrieverDataProvider file is this:

```
using BtLib;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ilimitada.AccesoDatos.Pervasive.Btrieve
{
    public class BtrieveDataProvider<T> : IPervasive<T>, IDisposable
    where T : class
    {
        private static IUnityContainer container;

        private short keyBufLen;

        private ushort structSize;

        private IntPtr pointer;

        private byte[] positionBlock;

        private byte[] keyBuffer;

        private string bufferName;

        private bool isDisposed;

        private LockBias lockbias;

        public T DataBuffer
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public short KeyNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public short Status
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public BtrieveDataProvider(string fullFilePath, ushort structSize)
        {
            this.bufferName = fullFilePath;
            this.keyBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.bufferName);
            this.keyBuffer = new byte[255];
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.bufferName);
            Array.Copy(bytes, this.keyBuffer, (int)bytes.Length);
            this.positionBlock = new byte[128];
            this.keyBufLen = 128;
            this.structSize = structSize;
            this.pointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.KeyNumber = 0;
            this.Status = -1;
            this.lockbias = LockBias.NoLock;
        }

        public void AbortTransaction()
        {
            byte[] numArray = new byte[128];
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.bufferName);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.AbortTrans, numArray, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, bytes, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
        }

        public void BeginTransaction(bool concurrent)
        {
            byte[] numArray = new byte[128];
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.bufferName);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            if (!concurrent)
            {
                this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.BeginTrans, numArray, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, bytes, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.BeginConCurrentTransaction, numArray, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, bytes, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            }
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            this.keyBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.bufferName);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.Close, this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
        }

        public static IPervasive<T> Create(string fullFilePath, ushort structSize)
        {
            BtrieveDataProvider<T>.container = new UnityContainer();
            BtrieveDataProvider<T>.container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
            IUnityContainer unityContainer = BtrieveDataProvider<T>.container;
            InjectionMember[] interceptor = new InjectionMember[] { new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>(), null };
            object[] objArray = new object[] { fullFilePath, structSize };
            interceptor[2] = new InjectionConstructor(objArray);
            unityContainer.RegisterType<IPervasive<T>, BtrieveDataProvider<T>>(interceptor);
            return BtrieveDataProvider<T>.container.Resolve<IPervasive<T>>(new ResolverOverride[0]);
        }

        public bool Create(IntPtr pointerStructure, ushort size)
        {
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.Create, this.positionBlock, pointerStructure, ref size, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            if (this.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool Delete()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.Delete, this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 8)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!this.isDisposed)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (BtrieveDataProvider<T>.container != null)
                    {
                        BtrieveDataProvider<T>.container.Dispose();
                    }
                    this.isDisposed = true;
                    this.Close();
                }
                catch (System.Exception exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void EndTransaction()
        {
            byte[] numArray = new byte[128];
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.bufferName);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.EndTrans, numArray, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, bytes, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
        }

        public void FinishtLockRecord()
        {
            this.lockbias = LockBias.NoLock;
        }

        public void GetDirect()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.GetDirect, this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
        }

        public bool GetEqual(string condition)
        {
            this.keyBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(condition);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetEqual, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 4)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool GetFirst()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetFirst, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 9)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool GetGreater(string condition)
        {
            this.keyBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(condition);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetGreater, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 9)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool GetGreaterOrEqual(string condition)
        {
            this.keyBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(condition);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetGreaterOrEqual, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 9)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool GetLast()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetLast, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 9)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool GetLessThan(string condition)
        {
            this.keyBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(condition);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetLessThan, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 9)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool GetLessThanOrEqual(string condition)
        {
            this.keyBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(condition);
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetLessThanOrEqual, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 9)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool GetNext()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetNext, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 8 && this.Status != 9)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public void GetPosition()
        {
            ushort num = 4;
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.GetPosition, this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref num, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 8)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
        }

        public bool GetPrevious()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Native.AddLockBias(Operation.GetPrevious, this.lockbias), this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 8 && this.Status != 9 && this.Status != 60 && this.Status != 62 && this.Status != 64)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public int GetStat(BtrieveStatistic typeStatistic)
        {
            short num = 0;
            int nroReg = 0;
            byte[] numArray = new byte[128];
            TypeCreate typeCreate = new TypeCreate();
            ushort num1 = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf<TypeCreate>(typeCreate);
            IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)num1);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<TypeCreate>(typeCreate, intPtr, true);
            num = Native.BtrCall(Operation.Stat, this.positionBlock, intPtr, ref num1, numArray, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            if (num == 0)
            {
                Marshal.PtrToStructure<TypeCreate>(intPtr, typeCreate);
                switch (typeStatistic)
                {
                    case BtrieveStatistic.RecordNumber:
                    {
                        nroReg = typeCreate.NroReg;
                        break;
                    }
                    case BtrieveStatistic.KeyNumber:
                    {
                        nroReg = typeCreate.IndexCount;
                        break;
                    }
                    case BtrieveStatistic.RecordLength:
                    {
                        nroReg = typeCreate.RecLength;
                        break;
                    }
                    case BtrieveStatistic.SegmentNumber:
                    {
                        nroReg = (int)typeCreate.Keys.Length;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intPtr);
            if (num != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(num);
            }
            return nroReg;
        }

        public bool Insert()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.Insert, this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public bool Open(OpenMode openMode = 0)
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            int num = 0;
            do
            {
                this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.Open, this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, (short)openMode);
                num++;
            }
            while (num <= 3 && this.Status == 3012);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 12)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }

        public void StartLockMultiRecord()
        {
            this.lockbias = LockBias.MultiNoWait;
        }

        public void StartLockRecord()
        {
            this.lockbias = LockBias.SingleNoWait;
        }

        public bool Update()
        {
            this.pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)this.structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(this.DataBuffer, this.pointer, true);
            this.Status = Native.BtrCall(Operation.Update, this.positionBlock, this.pointer, ref this.structSize, this.keyBuffer, this.keyBufLen, this.KeyNumber);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(this.pointer, this.DataBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(this.pointer);
            if (this.Status != 0 && this.Status != 8)
            {
                throw new BtrieveException(this.Status);
            }
            return this.Status == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If I compile the solution is compiled without problems, the dll is put on the bin folder, but it looks like it cant be found by the program.

Help please.

Comment: What does that message mean? Please translate it to English.

Comment: Do you have a Pervasive Engine / Client installed on this machine?  The error indicates a problem with either the DLL or one of its dependencies.  Make sure the W3BTRV7.DLL is in a directory on the system path.

Comment: nop, but we figured it out after asking this question, using dependency walker we found the real name of the dll, and with the dll we found  their documentation and that we needed pervasive engine installed, downloading it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your app launching from the `bin` directory?
if not, you need to copy that library to the directory where the executable file is located.

Comment: when I press F5 yes, and the dll is also there on the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case I clicked true in combo of 32 bits app. You will find it in your advanced configuration of your pool.

[image]